# how to add other dataframe attributes to the network according to the node id in networkx?

Tags: dataframe, networkx

I have undirected graph which includes nodes;

```
G.nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, I wanted add another dataframe attributes to these nodes according to node ID;

| Node ID | Attribute (degree) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

then, final network dictionary should be display as follows;

```
dict(G.nodes)= 
{1: {'degree': 5},
 3: {'degree': 2},
 4: {'degree': 2},
 5: {'degree': 4},
 16: {'degree': 20}
```

Please, give me solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Craft a dictionary from your DataFrame and use [`set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html):

```
d = (df.set_index('Node ID')[['Attribute (degree)']]
       .set_axis(['degree'], axis=1).to_dict('index')
    )
# {1: {'degree': 2}, 2: {'degree': 5}, 3: {'degree': 2}, 4: {'degree': 1}}

nx.set_node_attributes(G, d)

dict(G.nodes)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'degree': 2}, 2: {'degree': 5}, 3: {'degree': 2}, 4: {'degree': 1}}
```